# Object/Relational mapping

Tags: java, orm

In our java project, We decided to use ORM object/relational mapping technique in objects' persisting.

But we hesitate to use a specific framework to do this.So, what is the best framework for java can do this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587634/object-relational-mapping/587640#587640) says, Hibernate is an excellent choice.

A (not-exhaustive) list can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#Java)

Hibernate is a superset of [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API). If you stay within the bounds of the JPA, then you can theoretically switch to a differenct JPA implementation at a later point...

Answer (score 8):

[Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) is an excellent choice.

Answer (score 2):

As [toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3295/toolkit) said about what [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1551/chris-ballance) says, [Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587634/object-relational-mapping/587640#587640) is the choice.

:D :D :D :D

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate of course, but if you seek standardizations, then JPA or JDO